# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error displayed when run soapUI testsuite through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, soapui

When i am running testsuite through jenkins, 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' error displayed in logs.
The line where error occurred.

```
def randomuserserial = Long.toUnsignedString(new Random().nextLong().abs(), 16).toUpperCase()
```

No error occurred when i run the same suite in my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with SoapUI(5.3.0) version installed in Jenkins Server.
After updated to latest version (5.4.0), it works fine.

Comment: Strange. But nice to know.

Comment: true tried the command on soapui 5.3.0 it was giving error. Once i upgraded its gone. Looks like the limit of the variable is increased in latest version

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your requirement is to generate a random unsigned long number. So you can try something like this :

```
def min = 1000000000000000
def max = 9223372036854775807

def rand = new Random()
int range = max-min
def random_long = rand.nextInt(range) + min

def randomuserserial = random_long.toString().toUpperCase()
```

This should fix your issue.